# How to execute sql file via PL/SQL (the name of the sql file is know at execution time)

Tags: plsql, sqlplus

I need to write a PL/SQL bloc that executes an sql file. the thing is that the name of the sql file is determined at the execution time.

This is a snippet of what i'm trying to do here :

```
begin
  @'OracleV5\'||DBMS_DB_VERSION.VERSION||'g\script.sql';   
end;
/
```

PL/SQL doesn't seem to accept this kind of code :-(

any help please?

Comment: `@` is an sqlplus symbol, not a pl/sql symbol.

Answer (score 1):

The PLSQL block is executed in the database. The problem is how to access the SQL file and execute it's contents. 
The file needs to be in a location where the database has access to it. You can then create a directory object to access the location and read the file content using utl_file or by opening the file as a Blob using Bfile.

(sorry for the very abstract answer but that's all I've got time for now)

Comment: i don't have a problem regarding the location of the sql file. in fact the PL/SQL block is not in the database side but in a another sql file at the same directory as the first sql file.

Comment: @SamiBOB: PL/SQL is always executed at the server, not the client. You can never access files on the client machine from the database. To achieve what you'r attempting, the best you can do is use a SQL*Plus script.

Answer (score 0):

try execute immediate .   [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/executeimmediate_statement.htm) might be helpgul